# Unable to setup MySQL data source in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, jboss7.x

I am working on a Spring MVC app using sprint MVC 4, MySQL and JBoss 7.1.1. I am trying to set MySQL data source in JBoss.

I have created a file 'module.xml' in `JBoss 7.1.1\modules\com\mysql\main` directory. Also I have copied mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar in same directory. Following is the content of `module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
     <resource-rootpath="mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar"/>              
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
     <module name="javax.api"/>
     <module name="javax.transaction"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Following is the data source section in `standalone.xml`:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySQLPoolFirstPoolName" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/dbname</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>xxxxxxxxxx</user-name>
                        <password>xxxxxxxxxxx</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

When I start JBoss, it shows following error:

```
New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
service jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:/MySqlDS]
```

I have tried many solutions from web, but not able to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try add the `driver-class` to datasource configuration.

Eg:

```xml
<datasources>
    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySQLPoolFirstPoolName" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/dbname</connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        <driver>com.mysql</driver>
        <pool>
            <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>xxxxxxxxxx</user-name>
            <password>xxxxxxxxxxx</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
            <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried by adding driver-class, but it still is showing error.